# How to dynamically avoid 'use module' to reduce memory footprint

Tags: perl, memory-management

Given the following module:

```
package My::Object;

use strict;
use warnings;

use My::Module::A;
use My::Module::B;
use My::Module::C;
use My::Module::D;

...
1;
```

I would like to be able to call My::Object in the next 2 scenarios:

1. Normal use

   use My::Object;

   My::Module->new();
2. Reduced memory use. Call the same object but with a condition or a flag telling the object to skip the use modules to reduce memory usage. Somehow like:

   use My::Object -noUse;

   My::Module->new();

If tried the [Perl if condition](http://perldoc.perl.org/if.html) without success.

The problem I'm having it's with big objects with a lot of uses, then only loading this object consumes a lot of RAM. I know I can refactor them but it will be wonderful if somehow I can avoid these uses when I'm sure none of them is used on the given scenario.

One solution will be to replace all uses with requires on all places when the modules are needed, but I don't see convenient when some of them are used in a lot of methods.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can your show your attempt from 2?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen It was something like what Sobrique suggested in his answer. But I could'nt make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The native pragma [`autouse`](http://perldoc.perl.org/autouse.html) will load modules needed when plain *subroutines* are called:

```
use autouse 'My::Module::A' => qw(a_sub);
# ... later ...
a_sub "this will dynamically load My::Module::A";
```

For proper OO methods, [`Class::Autouse`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class::Autouse) will load modules (classes) when *methods* are called:

```
use Class::Autouse;
Class::Autouse->autouse( 'My::Module::A' );
# ... later ...
print My::Module::A->a_method('this will dynamically load My::Module::A');
```

Answer (score 2):

What I think you're looking for is perhaps [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) - require is evaluated later so you can use it successfully in a conditional:

```
if ( $somecondition ) {
    require Some::Module;
}
```

Of course, you won't be able to do `Some::Module->new()` if you've not loaded it - there's just no way around that.

Where `use` is triggered at compile time (and thus will trigger warnings under `perl -c` if the module is unavailable) `require` happens are runtime. You should probably test if require was successful as a result.

e.g.:

```
if ( $somecondition ) {
    eval { require Some::Module };
    warn "Module Not loaded: ".$@ if $@;
}
```

Otherwise you may be looking for:

[Is it possible to pass parameters to a Perl module loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880616/is-it-possible-to-pass-parameters-to-a-perl-module-loading)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package MyObject;

sub import {
    my ( $package, $msg ) = @_;
    if ( defined $msg and $msg eq "NO_USE" ) {
        #don't load module
    }
    else {
        require XML::Twig;
    }
}

1;
```

And then call:

```
use if $somecondition, MyObject => ( 'NO_USE'  );
```

Or just simpler:

```
use MyObject qw( NO_USE );
```

Edit:

After a bit of fiddling with 'use' - there's a couple of gotchas, in that `use if` doesn't seem to like lexical variables. So you need to do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package MyObject;
use strict;
use warnings;

our $import_stuff = 1;

sub import {
    my ( $package, $msg ) = @_;
    if ( $msg and $msg eq "NO_USE" ) {
        $import_stuff = 0;
    }
    use if $import_stuff, 'Text::CSV';
}

1;
```

And call:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use MyObject qw( NO_USE );
use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper \%INC;
my $test = Text::CSV -> new();
```

(Which errors if you set `NO_USE` and doesn't otherwise).

I *think* that's an artifact of `use` being a compile time directive still, so requires a (package scoped) condition.

Comment: Hmm, this is perhaps a bit more about applying a conditional to the modules being loaded then.

Comment: *"`use if` doesn't seem to like lexical variables"* That's not true. The tricky part is getting a lexical variable declared and defined at compile time *before* the `use if`.  Something like `my $wanted; BEGIN { $wanted = 1 } use if $wanted, 'My::Module'` will work fine

Comment: but nothing passed to import is going to be available at compile time, so `use if` isn't going to work here at all

Comment: @ysth Ah, good point, I missed the part in the question about wanting to do this with import.